# Nested json structure

Tags: java, json, serialization, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create a dynamodb which has following features

1. PK: `orderId`
2. RK: `date`
3. shipped: `Y|N`
4. details: `<nested json structure>`

Point 4 is the one which i am really confused about. If i keep `details` field as a string and try to store `json` as string, AWS **escape** `"` characters i.e., `{"onlineStore" : "283"}` becomes `{\"onlineStore\": \"283\"}`

This get's retrieved properly from dynamodb with `details` as string mappings but if i have to convert it to a pojo using jackson, I have to take care of those `\`.

So as an alternative, I thought that i could create `details` a **POJO** i.e.,

```
public class OrderDetail{
    private int onlineStore;
    // rest of the JSON properties

    @JsonCreator
    public OrderDetail (@JsonProperty("onlineStore") int onlineStore, ...){
        this.onlineStore = onlineStore;         
    }
}
```

With the above implementation, i get error that `DynamoDBMappingException: Couldn't convert attribte`.

The `OrderDetail` type is a common type which is being used between my JSON REST Response as well so i want to avoid putting `DynamoDB` specific annotation here.

Now the question is **what should be proper way to implement it**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [DynamoDB Mapper class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) to perform the CRUD operation, you can use the annotation `@DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson` to save the order details.

[DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson.html) - Check this link for more details

**DynamoDBMapper class:-**

> The AWS SDK for Java provides a DynamoDBMapper class, allowing you to
>   map your client-side classes to DynamoDB tables. To use
>   DynamoDBMapper, you define the relationship between items in a
>   DynamoDB table and their corresponding object instances in your code.
>   The DynamoDBMapper class enables you to access your tables, perform
>   various create, read, update and delete (CRUD) operations, and execute
>   queries.

**Sample Implementation:-**

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Order")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3534650012619938612L;

    private String orderId; 

    private OrderDetail orderDetail;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "orderId")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson
    public OrderDetail getOrderDetail() {
        return orderDetail;
    }

    public void setOrderDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail) {
        this.orderDetail = orderDetail;
    }

}

public class OrderDetail implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7312390212027563305L;
    private Integer onlineStore;

    public Integer getOnlineStore() {
        return onlineStore;
    }

    public void setOnlineStore(Integer onlineStore) {
        this.onlineStore = onlineStore;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderDetail [onlineStore=" + onlineStore + "]";
    }

}

public Order loadOrder(String orderId) {

    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);

    Order order = dynamoDBMapper.load(Order.class, orderId,
            new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT));

    System.out.println("Order : " + order.toString());
    System.out.println("Order Id : " + order.getOrderId());
    System.out.println("Order Detail : " + order.getOrderDetail());
    System.out.println("Online store : " + order.getOrderDetail().getOnlineStore());

    return order;

}
```

**Output:-**

```
Order Id : 0beced28-f1de-4c44-8094-6de687d25e97
Order Detail : OrderDetail [onlineStore=1]
Online store : 1
```

**Data in DDB:-**

As you mentioned, the order detail will be stored with escape characters. However, when you get the data using DynamoDB mapper, it will be in deserialized form (i.e. as POJO object).

[image]